# Gradient at a point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have seen that to find the gradient at a point on a curve this is the equation,

e.g $G$ at a point $= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$

given $2x^2-5x$, find the gradient to the tangent at the point $x=2$.

skipping a few steps to get to :
$$
 (1) \qquad      =   \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{3h+2h^2}{h}
$$
$$ 
 (2) \qquad        =   \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{h(3+2h)}{h}
$$
$$ 
   (3) \qquad    =   \lim_{h \to 0} (3+2h)   
$$ 
$$
     (4) \qquad    =              3
$$
between $(3)$ and $(4)$, how is $(3+2h)$ transformed into $3$? what happens to the $2h$? what step am I not understanding??

Comment: If $h \to 0$ than $2h \to 0$.

Comment: thank you!! That makes sense! Many thank you, I was overlooking that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As $h \to 0$, we have $2h \to 0$ and thus $3+2h \to 3$.